# Condensing Python For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I was wondering if it is possible to condense this double for loop within a web scrape. This works fine, but I just want to see if it's possible to condense to a single line:

```
small_form = race.find_all('table', attrs={'class' : 'longFormSummary'})[0]
count = (len(small_form.find_all('tr'))-1)    
for x in range(0,count):
     a = small_form.find_all('tr')[x]
     test = [s.text.strip().lower() for s in a.find_all('td')]
```

I tried a few different ways but was unable to condense the test = line to absorb the two above.

Edit: I tried the below with no luck:

```
test = [a.text.strip().lower() for a in e.find_all('td') for e in small_form.find_all('tr')]
```

Print of correct output is here:

```
['1', '5822', "nic's karma", '', '64', '90', '$8', '']
```

Comment: Please include fragment of the HTML and what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What is `count`? Is it just `len(small_form.find_all('tr'))`?

Comment: And fix indentation.

Comment: Is there any more code in that loop after the `test` assignment? Otherwise your loop keeps overwriting `test` and you only get the `test` corresponding to the last count.

Comment: Sorry yes, it just adds the list as a row to a pandas df using something like results.loc[len(results)] = test